# Xamarin dynamic tabbed page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image: result]

Now, this works perfectly fine, if I use it hard-coded like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WunderlistApp.View.MainPage"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="RallyPodium &amp; Reporting" />
    <ContentPage Title="Projecten voor klanten" />
    <ContentPage Title="School" />
</TabbedPage>
```

Nown what I want to do, is I want to make those tabs "dynamically". What do I mean with this, is that I want to "link" the title from an API (data is bindable from the .cs file) to the xaml file (or make it in C#, but I have no clue how). And then the content must appear from it some way or another (it's just basically a listview)...

So if someoune could help me out here?

This is the .cs code:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //GetFolders();
        }

        private async Task GetFolders()
        {
            List<Folder> folders = await ApiManager.GetFoldersAsync();

            //foreach (Folder f in folders)
            //{
            //    Debug.WriteLine("Folder name: {0}", f.title);
            //}

            //lvwMainTasksList.ItemsSource = folders;
        }
```

I also have no idea how I can link a contentPage to the tabbed pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var f in folders) {
  // if you are in code-behind of a TabbedPage, "this" will be TabbedPage
  this.Children.Add(new ContentPage { Title = f });
}
```

Comment: So, I have this now: https://pastebin.com/bBmumeVR But it doesn't load any content here... :(

Comment: What is MainPage?  If it's your TabbedPage, then you don't need to create an explicit TabbedPage

Comment: What do you mean? Like I have a tabbed page as MainPage now?

Comment: what TYPE is MainPage - does it inherit from TabbedPage?  Or something else?

Comment: MainPage is in the xaml file a TabbedPage, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Awesome! But how can I append a content to it?